# how to understand (clk'event and clk='1')

Tags: vhdl

Since (clk'event and clk='1') is commonly used to describe a rising edge event of the clk signal, I have the following questions:

(1) how to understand the "and"? does it mean "then"?

(2) how about (clk='1' and clk'event)? is it the same as the above?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. "and" means logical "and", as in "both of these things should be true for the expression to return true".
2. Yes, this would be logically equivalent.

Having said this, what you should use in this scenario is the `rising_edge` function, for example `if (rising_edge(clk)) then`. This and the accompanying `falling_edge` function work correctly in more scenarios, and are more readable.

Comment: I know the "and" is the logical "and". My question is why (clk'event and clk='1') can be used to describe the rising edge event. It seems that "it changes and "then" it becomes '1'".

Comment: Hmm, it really is just a logical "and", sorry. Imagine a simulator running your code. It gets to an `if` statement, and looks at the conditions at that instant in time. Is there an event on `clk` at this time? Yes. Is it high at this time? Yes. The logical "and" of these is interpreted as "there is a rising edge", because the signal has changed, and it's now `'1'`. This is also the reason that you should use the `rising_edge` function; what if the previous value of the signal was `'Z'`? Should we really interpret this as a rising edge? The `'event` style answers "yes".

Comment: Thank you! it is about the meaning of "'event", which is "has changed".